# Preserving the alpha channel when quantizing image in ImageMagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm currently trying to quantize an image using ImageMagick in PHP, which works fine, except the alpha channel isn't preserved. If I iterate through each pixel and count the number of pixels with an alpha value of 0 before quantization, it is correct, but after quantization, nearly all of the image has an alpha value of 0.

Is there a way of preserving this data through the quantization process?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem? I'm having the same trouble....

Comment: I think I ended up with a hacky solution where I just copied the alpha values for each pixel from the original image or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

When using the command line imagemagick tools, there is a way to ignore the alpha channel:

```
convert alpha_gradient.png -quantize transparent +dither -colors 15 alpha_colors_15qt.png
```

The option "-quantize transparent" does that. What does the PHP look like?

Comment: $img->quantizeImage( 8, Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB, 0, false, false );

The first argument is the number of colors, followed by the color space. Due to a complete absence of documentation for the PHP implementation, I'm not really sure what the third and last arguments do, although the fourth is dithering.

Comment: Have run in to the same problem. Did you find out how it can be done in PHP?